# Prove that $0$ is not a cluster point for the set A

Tags: real-analysis

> Given the set {$A = {x \in\mathbb{R} | x = 0}$ or ${|{x}| ≥ 1}$}, write the set of all the cluster
>   points of A. (Not required to prove anything)

Which i've answered as {${0}$}$\cup[1,+\infty)$

> Given the set A defined in the previous part, prove that 0 is not a cluster point for the set
>   A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cluster point (or limit point) of a set can be thought of intuitively as a point with "neighboring" points that are arbitrarily close.  In slightly math-ier language,

> We say that $x$ is a limit point of $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if for all positive numbers $\varepsilon$, there exists some number $y \in E$ with $y\ne x$ such that $|x-y| < \varepsilon$.

In the case of your set $A$, zero is not a limit point, because it doesn't have any "neighbors" in $A$.  For example, if we take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, we cannot find any point $y$ in $A$ (other than $0$) such that $|0-y| < \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The neighborhood $(-1/2,1/2)$ does not meet $A$ anywhere except at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to include the interval $(- \infty, -1]$ in the cluster points, as $A$ contains it.

Now take the closure of $A$, which is $\bar{A} = (- \infty, -1] \cup [1,\infty)$. Now the closure of a set is the union of the interior and the cluster points. As $0$ isn't in $\bar{A}$, it's not a cluster points. Hence the proof.